# Print Dialog Extension - Connecting to Network when running the PDE on a sandboxed app

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, driver, sandbox

I am creating a Print Dialog Extension (PDE) for Mac OSX.
In that PDE, I need to connect to the network for authentication.

However, due to sandboxing, when I tried the PDE in TextEdit, I cannot connect to LDAP.
From the console, it says sandboxd denied network-outbound for TextEdit. 
Apparently, the sandboxed TextEdit does not allow network connections.

I just like to ask, what is the best way to fix this?
How can I enable network connection in my PDE, even if the app it runs on does not allow it?
Can I also extend the sandbox profile of an app using my PDE (to add network connection entitlements)?

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Currently, I am looking at XPC services. Right now, XPC seems to not work, maybe because the PDE plugin runs on top of an app, e.g. TextEdit, and my XPC service is not within the Main App's bundle.